# Xero failed to validate signature using omniauth-xero and xeroixer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xero-api

I'm working on a rails application that is integrating with Xero. I'm using `omniauth-xero` gem to authenticate my users, and the `xeroizer` gem to interact with Xero's API. I am storing the token, secret token on a model associated with the user. I'm able to access the xeroizer client and see that the access tokens are matching what I'm storing. But when I try to do a basic get request, I get a 401, signature invalid: Failed to validate signature. I'm confused on what the error could be referring to as I have no way to touch the signature between using each of the gems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set a password while export the pfx file and you missed in your code?